# Select winning women in database SQL

Tags: mysql, database, querying

I was wondering how I should retrieve the winning women in my database.
The winning men and women of the contest are:

Ed Reynolds Men 41 minutes

Erna Obrien Female 43 minutes

It's possible to retrieve the winning men by using

MIN(performance_in_minutes) because then I will get the overall winner and this happens to be a men

But how do I retrieve the winning female? I tried following query but this won't work...

```
SELECT A.Fname, A.Sex, PI.Performance_in_minutes
from athlete as A LEFT OUTER JOIN participation_ind as PI on A.athleteID = PI.athleteID
WHERE eventID = 35
AND PI.Performance_in_minutes = 
    (SELECT MIN(PI.performance_in_minutes) FROM participation_ind PI WHERE PI.eventID = 35 AND A.Sex = 'F')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your query.

Your sub-query ***attempts*** to get the lowest time for event 35 for females.  Unfortunately, where you have `A.sex = 'f'`, your inner query doesn't have an `A` table any where.  *(You need to include the `JOIN` on the `athlete` table in the sub-query too.)*

```
AND PI.Performance_in_minutes = (
        SELECT MIN(PI.performance_in_minutes)
          FROM participation_ind PI
    INNER JOIN athlete A ON A.athleteID = PI.athleteID
         WHERE PI.eventID = 35
           AND A.Sex = 'F'
    )
```

Without doing that, your sub-query's `WHERE` clause is referring to the outer-query's `A` table.  Which isn't accomplishing anything.

Then, you also need to filter the outer-query to females only...  *(If you don't and a male athlete happened to finish with the same time as the winning female athlete(s), that male athlete would also be returned.)*

```
SELECT
    A.Fname, A.Sex, PI.Performance_in_minutes
FROM
    athlete             A
INNER JOIN
    participation_ind   PI
        ON A.athleteID = PI.athleteID
WHERE
    PI.eventID = 35
    AND A.Sex = 'F'
    AND PI.Performance_in_minutes = (
           SELECT
               MIN(PI.performance_in_minutes)
           FROM
               athlete             A
           INNER JOIN
               participation_ind   PI
                   ON A.athleteID = PI.athleteID
           WHERE
               PI.eventID = 35
               AND A.Sex = 'F'
        )
```

This can be simplified a lot if you know there is only ever ***one*** winner.  But the sub-query version is better as it accounts for the rare scenarios where two or more athletes are tied for 1st place.

You can also reduce some of the repetition in the code by joining on to the sub-query, rather than using it in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    A.Fname, A.Sex, PI.Performance_in_minutes
FROM
(
    SELECT
        PI.eventID,
        A.Sex,
        MIN(PI.performance_in_minutes)   AS performance_in_minutes
    FROM
        participation_ind   PI
    INNER JOIN
        athlete             A
            ON A.athleteID = PI.athleteID
    GROUP BY
        PI.eventID,
        A.Sex
)
    winning_times
INNER JOIN
    participation_ind   PI
        ON  PI.eventID                = winning_times.eventID
        AND PI.performance_in_minutes = winning_times.performance_in_minutes
INNER JOIN
    athlete             A
        ON  A.athleteID = PI.athleteID
        AND A.Sex       = winning_times.Sex
WHERE
        winning_times.eventID = 35
    AND winning_times.Sex     = 'F'
```

Now you can change which event or sex you want to analyse, just by changing one `WHERE` clause, rather than two.